# Sending jwt token redirecting to a single page app

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, jwt, authorization

In my server I get a request from an external app, check that its validity and then create jwt token and redirect to my single my app. I am thinking about two posible options.

One is to put that jwt token in a cookie and redirect to my app, then read the cookie from js side and use it to make api request from my spa app.

Another one is to redirect to my spa like this: https://my-spa.com/?token=jwtoken, then read query param of token with js and use it later for api calls.

The first option presents one trouble: let's say I have the same user call this scenario from two different browser tabs to two slightly different server url, which will generate different jwt token encoding in it the different url's context. So the user would get two different jwt tokens in in each tab's response via cookie. However, the response of the last browser tab would overwrite the cookie from the first tab. Then when the user hits refresh on the first tab, the overwritten cookie (with the context from the cookie from another tab) would be sent and that would be incorrect.

So I guess I only have the second option, where the user can refresh the page and my server would still get the correct token in query param from each browser tab. Is there something wrong with approach?

Comment: Could you elaborate how `that would be incorrect`?

Comment: @Hiro, I've edited the question a bit, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: ummm, i'm confused since cookies are meant to be shared in browsers(between tabs) and I'm not following the issue of the  "context" that you speak of.

Comment: Right, the cookie is per domain, so when 2 tabs make a request to a server and the server responds with a different data in a cookie to each of those request, when it's done,  the browser will have a cookie with data from the second request. With context I refer, that depending of what endpoint you hit in the server, it will encode some data related to that endpoint and put it into the cookie to send back to the server.

Comment: Why do you put endpoint specific data in jwt? That seems wrong. You could, but wrong.

Comment: I don't put endpoint specific data in jwt. It is a simple example to illustrate the situation.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not getting you. Could you perhaps show examples of "different" data?